# Can I use verb "pass" to tell someone to ignore a question?

Tags: word-usage

If I leave a message to someone such like as "Can you please bala bala bala?"

After a while, I want to let him skip my question.

So I said "Please pass it" but is this correct?

Or I should use "Please ignore it" instead?

Comment: The terms _skip_ and _ignore_ would be better in that context.

Comment: *Should I use "Please ignore it" instead?* Yes.

Comment: I first heard 'pass' meaning 'I'm not going to attempt to answer that question' in the BBC TV quiz _Mastermind_, and the usage has spread to other quizzes. It can mean 'miss your turn in a game'. I don't think your correspondent would understand it in the sense you mean, though.

Comment: 'Pass' is often said by people being asked questions they cannot answer.

Comment: Thank all of you, I understand.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Does "pass" mean OK or not OK?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468093). I am, however, not voting to close it as a duplicate, because the older question is closed, and the ambiguity of *pass* deserves to have an open question somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Pass* is an **extremely** common verb with many uses both transitive and
intransitive, including many phrasal or prepositional versions. Some
transitive senses accept an indirect object as recipient.

- You can pass on the left not the right.
- You can pass someone the salt, and you pass the salt to somone.
- You can pass (or pass by) the salt (without taking any for yourself).
- You can pass the salt on (or onwards or along).
- You can pass (or take a pass) on the salt today if you don't care for any.
- You can pass on to the next step once you've completed the current one.
- An old dog can pass on (and go to to doggy-heaven).

Passing a question usually means answering it correctly, like passing an
exam, but can sometimes mean other things.  It doesn't usually mean
bypassing the question.  Passing **on** a question means not answering it.
So does **taking** a pass on a question.  Passing someone a question means
giving it to them.